# what it means on( 'click.something', function() {..}); in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I familiar with structure like below:

```
on('click', function() {..});
```

But I found somewhere this type structure

```
on('click.something', function() {..});
```

what it means or what is the difference?

Comment: This is a valid question and it's difficult to google this one out if you're not familiar with it. It shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/).

On `click.something` , the **something** is the namespace by which you can bind and unbind the event suppose if you provide namespace in your code then you can easily unbind the event. See example below:

```
$(selector).on('click.something',function(){
//do stuff here


//and after the click you can unbind the event like this:
$(selector).off('click.something');

//but this won't work
$(selector).off('click'); 
});
```

Comment: The two links you provide have nothing to do with *event* namespaces.